# How do I return the value of a cell immediately to the left of a certain value in a column of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data. In A5:A200 I have aircraft velocities, in ascending order from 5 to 200. In B5:B200 I have the amount of lift the aircraft creates at each velocity, these values initially increase, reach a peak and then decrease.

I find the maximum lift the aircraft is able to create and show it in cell B1, I do this using MAX(B5:B200) in cell B1.

In cell B2, I want to show the velocity at which this max lift occurs. How do I do this? It will be the cell immediately to the left of the cell which contains the value of max lift.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641040/excel-vlookup-where-the-key-is-not-in-the-first-column/38641090#38641090

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this by using the following in cell B2.

=INDEX(A5:A200,MATCH(B1,B5:B200,0))